# Printing dynamic content with page breaks in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, printing

In my asp.net project I need to print a page with some dynamic content.I followed this article  http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=92 to achieve that and it works fine as long as the content I need to print fits in one page.

But in case of lengthy content, when I click on print button I see a print preview with all the content that needs to be printed and when printed it just prints the content that fits into one page.So I think when I call 'window.print()' it just prints whatever that can fit into a page and does not check if there is anymore content left to print on another page.And I am not sure how do I set the page breaks to get the entire content printed,as it is dynamic content.

Could someone please help me with this?

Thanks

**Edit:**

Here is some sample HTML rendered.

```
<table class="Main">
<tr>
<td class=”left bold”>
Some text
</td>
<td>
<span id="Label">Label</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
......
......
</tr>
......
......
......
<tr>
<td>
<table class= “productslist”>
<tbody>
<tr>....</tr>
<tr>....</tr>
<tr class=”productTextAlign”>  ......</tr>
<tr class=”additionalOptions”> ..... </tr>
<tr class=”additionalOptions”>.....</tr>

<tr class=”additionalOptions”>.....</tr>

<tr class=”additionalOptions”>.....</tr>

<tr class=”additionalOptions”>.....</tr>
<tr>...</tr>

<tr class=”productTextAlign”></tr>

<tr class=”additionalOptions”>.....</tr>

<tr class=”additionalOptions”>.....</tr>

<tr class=”additionalOptions”>.....</tr>

<tr class=”additionalOptions”>.....</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</td>
<tr>
</table>
```

the table with class is 'Main' is a html table and inside that there is another table with class 'productslist' which is actually a repeater. I am trying to apply the 'page break before' to this repeater using

```
table.productslist
{
page-break-before:auto;
}
```

which doesnt to work in FF6.0 and it seems to work fine in IE8.

Comment: FF6 is still new and probably has lots of bugs.

Comment: do you think it would work in a lower version of FF?

Comment: Have you not tried it???

Comment: I haven't yet.will give it a try.thanks

Comment: Just to confirm when 'page-break-before' set to 'auto' ,for a lengthy content,it will introduce a page break.right?

Comment: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/page-break-before  make sure you're developing this using more than one browser side-by-side :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an Active X control for this:

http://www.meadroid.com/scriptx/docs/printdoc.asp

Alternatively you could take a CSS approach:

http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+page+break

Comment: Thanks.I tried using 'Page-break-before: always' which seems to work fine.But I want a page break only if the content is lengthy.so I changed it to 'auto' which doesnt work.doesn't 'auto' supposed to work depending on content length?Please help.

Comment: Show us the markup of the page you're trying to print - is it static content, GridView? etc...

Comment: Ok,I have added some sample HTML to my original question.Please see.